# Do Aegis Augment Weapons option work on Mind Blades of Soul Knives?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, psionics

Do Aegis Augment Weapons option work on Mind Blades of Soul Knives? Does it also apply weather it is used as a melee or ranged weapon?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The soulknife’s form mind blade ability explicitly calls out the mind blade as a weapon, and the aegis’s augmented weapon ability applies to any weapon. It does not restrict the benefit to melee weapons, and so it could apply to any sort of mind blade you like—melee, thrown, or even the soulbolt’s ranged-weapon version.